# Почему не работает @Url.Action при ajax-запросе?

Tags: ajax, asp.net, маршрутизация

Есть необходимость получить некоторые данные для autocomplete ajax-запросом. Пересмотрел в инете кучу примеров и в каждом из них приводится примерно такой код:

```
data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")'
```

Однако, это не работает. Возможно, нужно сделать правильный роутинг, но у меня не выходит. Если же написать прямую ссылку вмеcто `target.attr("data-autocomplete-source")`, как показано в коде, то все работает.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".searchField").each(function () {
        var target = $(this);
        target.autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.post("/MyController/MyAction/", request, response);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    }); 
});
```

Роутинг:

```
routes.MapRoute (
 "AutocompleteSearch", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyAction" 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В роутинге принято указывать имена `contrller` и `action` без окончаний `...Controller` и `...Action`.

Соответственно, и в методе получения Url соблюдается такой же принцип:

```
@Url.Action("My", "My")
```

Рекомендую все же давать более понятные имена, чтобы не было путаницы.

Comment: MyController и MyAction я написал в качестве примера. Конечно я указываю без окончаний. Не в этом проблема

Comment: @user3576767 что у вас получается на месте `@Url.Action()` после рендеринга страницы?

Comment: После рендеринга тоже самое выражение @Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")

Comment: @user3576767 По всей видимости движок Razor воспринимает это как текст, а не как вычисляемое выражение. Посмотрите внимательно на то как выглядит ваша View, и в каком месте находится указанная строка. Можете добавить вашу View к вопросу - посмотрим вместе.

Comment: а другие Razor команды работают? у меня был опыт в 2015 студии, когда View файлы просто перестали работать. Помогла команда devenv.exe /ResetUserData